# Can we automate ETL in Azure?

Tags: automation, azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory

I am currently working on a very interesting ETL project using Azure to transform my data manually. However, transforming data manually can be exhausting and lengthy when I start having several source files to process. My pipeline is working fine for now because I have only a few files to transform but what if I have thousands of excel files?

So what I want to achieve is that I want to extend the project and extract the excel files that are coming from Email using the logic app then apply ETL directly on top of them. Is there any way I can automate ETL in Azure. Can I do ETL without modifying the pipeline for a different type of data manually? How can I make my pipeline flexible to be able to handle data transformation for various types of source data?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do ETL without modifying the pipeline for a different type of
>   data manually?

According to your description, i suppose that you already knew the [ADF connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/connector-reference-logicapps-connectors) is supported in the Logic App. You could execute ADF pipeline in the Logic App flow and even pass parameters into ADF pipeline.

Normally, the source and sink service should be fixed in one copy activity, but you could define dynamic file path in the datasets. So you don't need to create multiple copy activities.

If the data types are different, you could try to pass the parameter from Logic App into ADF. Then before the data transmission, you could use Switch activity to route the transmission into different branches.

[image]